# Default link to 'Parent' from 'Related' for bug-requirement association when user logs a new issue from manual test manager

Tags: visual-studio, microsoft-test-manager

Whenever an new bug is been created from MTM it is associated with the requirement with the link 'Related', I want to change the settings such that the bug is always associated to the requirement as 'Child'. Also I don't want to change it manually its has to be associated by default when I create a bug. Please let me know the steps for the same.

Comment: When create a new bug in MTM, it links to Requirement? How to achieve it? I can't see this in TFS 2015+VS 2015, could you share the steps? I would like to test it on my side.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any option to set this. You need to edit the link type to "Child" manually from "Links" tab when create the bug. Refer to this link for details:
[Creating a bug as a child link in MTM](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/26bbf7f2-db68-498d-8412-4bb3323dd4df/creating-a-bug-as-a-child-link-in-mtm?forum=vsmantest)